# Why Serail.readBytes() read garbage values?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

I'm writing a code where I read 6 digit characters through Bluetooth. This is my code to read values (I use Serial 1 ):

```
Serial.println("DAMN YOU");
char data[DATA_LENGTH+1];   //DATA_LENGTH is 6
data[DATA_LENGTH]='\n';
uint8_t actu_length,from_index,to_index,from_road=0,to_road=0;
if (Serial1.available() > 0){
     Serial1.readBytes(data,DATA_LENGTH);
     Serial.println("bla bla bal");
     Serial.println(data);
 }
```

but this gives some garbage values.

Why this is happening? Which important point I'm missing ?

Is there any other efficient way to read 6 digit through serial communication in arduino??

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`Serial1` may have only 1 byte received when `if (Serial1.available() > 0){` is true!

So reading 6 is most likely going to produce bad results.
Wait until you have what you need:

`if (Serial1.available() >= 6){`

As there is not enough data, `readBytes` will stop reading. If `data` is a local variable, the contents of the unwritten cells could be anything (you do not zero-initialize/fill with known data apart from the last cell).

Comment: it reads data but jumbled way. like if I send "123456" it receives " * 1 2 | 9 9 "

Comment: Did you wait until enough data had been received like I mentioned in my answer? And is your baud rate correct?

Comment: yes , I do .
and broad rate are same ( 9600 ) for serial communication and HC-05 Bluetooth module.